# Golang runtime UAC prompt "Access is denied."

Tags: go

I am trying to create some registry keys for a custom protocol handler (toaster-http://).
But when I try to read the root reg key to verify if it exists, I keep getting access is denied. Great! Windows does it's thing.

However, when I execute the same code, asking for a UAC prompt and pressing yes before the code gets executed; I still get access denied. Any help?

If relevant, I am running this in Wails, and the uac prompt get called with the executable "wailsbindings" from my temp dir.

```golang
func (t *Toaster) regCheck() error {
    // setup prompt
    verb := "runas"
    exe, _ := os.Executable()
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    args := strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " ")

    verbPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(verb)
    exePtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(exe)
    cwdPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(cwd)
    argPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(args)

    var showCmd int32 = 1 //SW_NORMAL

    // prompt for admin
    var err = windows.ShellExecute(0, verbPtr, exePtr, argPtr, cwdPtr, showCmd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // open reg key
    key, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.CLASSES_ROOT, PROTOCOL_REG_PATH, registry.ALL_ACCESS)
    if err != nil {
        if err == registry.ErrNotExist {
            return t.createRegKeys() // Not relevant for this question.
        }
        return errors.New("Error opening protocol registry key: " + err.Error())
    }
    key.Close()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Remember that `ShellExecute` with `"runas"` starts the NEW process as administrator, but the current process is going to continue on as an unprivileged user, and your next statement will cause a permission failure.  Perhaps you need to check whether you are admin first, and decide whether to do the relaunch OR do the `OpenKey` call.

Comment: Yes! I know this. The issue is in the new process. I have however solved it by not executing the code when "wailsbinding" is in os.Args[0]. Seems like Wails runs the code in order to compile it.

Answer (score -2):

Make a little .bat file and:

Run the Go program with administrative privileges: Right-click on the .bat file, and select

`Run as administrator`

from the context menu. Or, in the control panel under "User Accounts" / "User Accounts and Family Safety" -> "UAC settings / Change User Account Control Settings" you can adjust levels. The levels range from "Always notify" to "Never notify". You might have to restart the PC after this.

Comment: Not what I needed, appreciate you trying though. Why do it through a batch file? If we're right clicking on files anyways, right click on any executable or shortcut in windows; go to compatibility and check "run as administrator". Might save you some time in the future! :)